# How Snapshot testing works and what does toMatchSnapshot( ) function do in Jest Snapshot testing for React components?

Tags: reactjs, tdd, jestjs, snapshot

I am new to Jest testing and I was going through some examples of how test cases are written in Jest for React components. I came across Snapshot testing and was trying to understand what it is actually. And what I came across from the web is  **"Snapshot testing is a way to assert the result of a given test by generating a Json representation of its output."** So i have 2 doubts in Snapshot testing as of now:

**1)** Let's say we have a simple component which has a simple paragraph. So, if I try to test it using Snapshot testing, how will it convert that into the JSON representation of the component? And when is it useful?

**2)** I came across an example which looked like:

```
Wrapper = shallow(<First_Component />);
        
it("displays the result", () => {
   const test = Wrapper.find(Second_Component).length;
   expect(test).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

So, my question with the above code is how `toMatchSnapshot()` function works here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Snapshots` allows you to test if your component renders correctly so in your case

```
expect(Wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
```

If you want to test the number of occurence of a given component, import your second component and create your test:

```
it("displays the result", () => {
  const test = Wrapper.find(Second_Component).length;
  expect(test).toEqual(1); // or the number of occurrence you're expecting
});
```

If you're interested in JSON representation of your components you can use the [enzyme-to-json package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme-to-json) which serves this purpose

Comment: First of all,thanks for the answer. So, what I have understood is that Snapshots keep a copy a the component and then tries to compare it with the new component.And the comparision is done by toMatchSnapshot( ) function.Am I correct?

Comment: And if that's the case, then what is the difference between "expect(test).toEqual(1);" and "expect(Wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();" ?

Comment: Hi @pranami in fact in your code when you test `Wrapper.find(Component).length` you test the number of occurence of the component `Component` rendered in the component you are currently testing.
When you use `toMatchSnapshot` you are testing the 'overall' rendering of your component at a given time. This is why, say, you add an element inside your component you have to update the snapshot otherwise your test will fail.

Answer (score 31):

I think this question has not been answered with enough details!
Snapshot testing is based on history of your previous tests. When you first run a snapshot test it creates a text file including the textual render of your component tree. For example the following test:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer
    .create(<Link page="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</Link>)
    .toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Will generate the following text file:

```
exports[`renders correctly 1`] = `
<a
  className="normal"
  href="http://www.facebook.com"
  onMouseEnter={[Function]}
  onMouseLeave={[Function]}
>
  Facebook
</a>
`;
```

You need to keep these snapshot files in your VCS (git). When you make a change you can run these tests to see if it yet matches the snapshot text file or not.

for more reading study this document: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing

Comment: what is renderer ?

Comment: @AbdelhakAj I have updated my answer to satisfy your question, let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: My team's using Pipeline to run the test. How if the snapshot in git version is wrong and I need to update it? Should I commit with my local snapshot? If I do, will I pass the pipeline test on the first pull request?